# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when I print the prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

How to fix this error at `print(Classes[int(result)])`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Pre-Processing test data same as train data.
img_width=256
img_height=256
#model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

def prepare(img_path):
    img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(img_path, target_size=(256, 256))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = x/255
    return np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    
    
result = model.predict([prepare('/content/Soil_With_CNN/test/Clay/clay.test.100.jpg')])
disease=tf.keras.utils.load_img('/content/Soil_With_CNN/test/Clay/clay.test.100.jpg')
plt.imshow(disease)
#result.astype(int)
print(Classes[int(result)])
```

This code gives:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What are your results and what is its shape? At the moment you try to do something like `int([1,2])` and ìnt` does return a single number which cannot happen here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly guessing but assuming that it's a typical softmax output of multiple classes `result` holds then the probability for each class - for a single class prediction one wants the index of the highest entry.

`class_predictions = result.argmax(axis=-1)`

This would turn

```
[[0.1,0.9]
[0.6,0.4]]
```

into `[1,0]` which can be used to index your classes

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer as the final step ;)